# Finding SPX Index Option Data using xbbg or blpapi

Tags: python, bloomberg, blpapi

I am trying to find SPX INDEX option data from Bloomberg using Python. I would like to find spot prices, bids, asks, and implied volatilities for all of the options on a given date.

I know how to do this in Excel. There, I find all of the options listed for a given date (`BQL("filter(options('SPX Index'),expire_dt=='"08/15/21"')","ID_SECURITY_DES,px_bid().value","showids=false","cols=2;rows=495")`). This creates columns with option names, their prices, strikes, and whether or not they are calls. For each row I am then able to find all of the option information using BDH (for instance `BDH('SPX US 08/15/21 4440P Index','Ivol_MID','08/18/21','08/18/21')` and repeat for each field I want to find). However, I have tried to find this information using blpapi as follows:

```
import blpapi
import pandas
import csv
options = blpapi.SessionOptions()
options.setServerHost('localhost')
options.setServerPort(8194)

SECURITY_DATA = blpapi.Name("securityData")
SECURITY = blpapi.Name("security")
FIELD_DATA = blpapi.Name("fieldData")
FIELD_ID = blpapi.Name("fieldId")
OPT_CHAIN = blpapi.Name("OPT_CHAIN")
SECURITY_DES = blpapi.Name("Security Description")


def getOptionChain (sec_list):
    import pdb;pdb.set_trace()
    session = blpapi.Session(options)
    session.start()
    session.openService('//blp/refdata')
    refDataService = session.getService("//blp/refdata")
    request = refDataService.createRequest("ReferenceDataRequest")
    for s in sec_list:
        request.append("securities",s)
    request.append("fields", "OPT_CHAIN")
    cid = session.sendRequest(request)
    try:
        # Process received events
        while(True):
            # We provide timeout to give the chance to Ctrl+C handling:
            ev = session.nextEvent(500)
            response = []
            for msg in ev:
                if cid in msg.correlationIds():
                    securityDataArray = msg.getElement(SECURITY_DATA)
                    for securityData in securityDataArray.values():
                        fieldData = securityData.getElement(FIELD_DATA)
                        for field in fieldData.elements():
                            for n in range(field.numValues()):
                                fld = field.getValueAsElement(n)
                                response.append (fld.getElement(SECURITY_DES).getValueAsString())
            # Response completely received, so we could exit
            if ev.eventType() == blpapi.Event.RESPONSE:
                break
    finally:
        # Stop the session
        session.stop()
    return response



def getPX (sec_list, fld_list):
    opt_chain_list = getOptionChain(sec_list)
    session = blpapi.Session(options)
    session.start()
    session.openService('//blp/refdata')
    refDataService = session.getService("//blp/refdata")
    request = refDataService.createRequest("ReferenceDataRequest")
    for s in opt_chain_list:
        request.append("securities",s)
    for f in fld_list:
        request.append("fields",f)
    cid = session.sendRequest(request)
    try:
        # Process received events
        response = {}
        while(True):
            # We provide timeout to give the chance to Ctrl+C handling:
            ev = session.nextEvent(500)

            for msg in ev:
                if cid in msg.correlationIds():
                    securityDataArray = msg.getElement(SECURITY_DATA)
                    for securityData in securityDataArray.values():
                        secName = securityData.getElementAsString(SECURITY)
                        fieldData = securityData.getElement(FIELD_DATA)
                        response[secName] = {}
                        for field in fieldData.elements():
                            response[secName][field.name()] = field.getValueAsFloat()
            # Response completely received, so we could exit
            if ev.eventType() == blpapi.Event.RESPONSE:
                break
    finally:
        # Stop the session
        session.stop()                   
    tempdict = {}
    for r in response:
        tempdict[r] = pandas.Series(response[r])
        data = pandas.DataFrame(tempdict)
    return data
                

sec = ["SPX INDEX Equity"]
fld = ["PX_ASK","PX_BID"]
print(getPX(sec,fld))
```

Doing so gives me the following error:

```
blpapi.exception.InvalidArgumentException: Choice sub-element not found for name 'securityData'. (0x00020002)
```

Trying with xbbg

```
blp.bdh(tickers='SPX INDEX',flds=['PX_LAST','Bid','Ask'],start_date='09-26-20',end_date='09-30-20')
```

I get an empty dataframe.

I know if I list the specific option as I would in excel I can find my desired information, but how can I find a complete list of options to do so first? Additionally I would like to find a list of option expiries as well so I could query for given expiries.

Any suggestions on how to find historical option data for SPX INDEX options

**EDITS 08/19/21**

Changed to proper security names. Still not functioning.

When querying with `sec =  ["SPX US 08/15/21 4440P Index"]` and `fld = ["IVOL"]` I get the error `blpapi.exception.InvalidArgumentException: Choice sub-element not found for name 'securityData'.`

Comment: try to use proper security names like `SPX US 08/15/21 4440P Index` and `SPX Index`

Comment: Do you want to find all the options that were available on a given date in the past, or just those that are available today? Your BQL queries by expiry date, which is not (I think) a feature open to the python API. If you have a specific expiry date, then you can choose a reference date prior to that (say 1 day before) and pull in all the options that were available on that reference date (which will be a lot ~ 8k). You can then filter by the MATURITY to get just those for your chose expiry date. Though you run the risk of hitting the security download limit ...

Comment: Hi @DS_London. I want to find all of the options that were available on a given date in the past with a given expiry. I guess I could filter which would be fine. How would I find all of the options given on a date in the past?

Comment: The xbbg functions closely mirror those in Excel (after all they are wrapping the same underlying API), so you can try things out in Excel first. This function brings back the ids of all the options `=BDS("SPX Index","OPT_CHAIN","SINGLE_DATE_OVERRIDE","20200101")` for the options available on 1-Jan-20. Or at least 8000 of them. Bloomberg warns about truncation of the list. Unfortunately only Bloomberg's own ID comes back (when you use the date override), which is pretty useless for filtering. You can call `=BDP(BbgTkr,"SECURITY_DES")` to get the descriptive name.

Answer (score 0):

To find the historical values, you need to include the single date override as DS_London recommended. The code for getOptionChain is listed where queryDate is a datetime object that is the desired date and sec_list is the security we are querying for

```
 SECURITY_DATA = blpapi.Name("securityData")
SECURITY = blpapi.Name("security")
FIELD_DATA = blpapi.Name("fieldData")
FIELD_ID = blpapi.Name("fieldId")
OPT_CHAIN = blpapi.Name("OPT_CHAIN")
SECURITY_DES = blpapi.Name("Security Description")

def getOptionChain (sec_list,queryDate):
    session = blpapi.Session(options)
    session.start()
    session.openService('//blp/refdata')
    refDataService = session.getService("//blp/refdata")
    request = refDataService.createRequest("ReferenceDataRequest")
    for s in sec_list:
        request.append("securities",s)
    request.append("fields", "OPT_CHAIN")
    requestOverride = request.getElement('overrides').appendElement()
    requestOverride.setElement("fieldId","SINGLE_DATE_OVERRIDE")
        requestOverride.setElement('value',queryDate.strftime('%Y%m%d'))
    cid = session.sendRequest(request)
    try:
        # Process received events
        while(True):
            # We provide timeout to give the chance to Ctrl+C handling:
            ev = session.nextEvent(500)
            response = []
            for msg in ev:
                if cid in msg.correlationIds():
                    securityDataArray = msg.getElement(SECURITY_DATA)
                    for securityData in securityDataArray.values():
                        fieldData = securityData.getElement(FIELD_DATA)
                        for field in fieldData.elements():
                            for n in range(field.numValues()):
                                fld = field.getValueAsElement(n)
                                response.append(fld.getElement(SECURITY_DES).getValueAsString())
            # Response completely received, so we could exit
            if ev.eventType() == blpapi.Event.RESPONSE:
                break
    finally:
        # Stop the session
        session.stop()
    return response
```